# Getting a count of distinct entries and what that entry is

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say I have a `SELECT` query where I am getting `NAME`, `FOO1`, and `FOO2` columns from a table with data like below:

```
Frank    Bar1    Bar2
Frank    Biz1    Biz2
Frank    Baz1    Baz2
Joe      Bar1    Baz2
Joe      Biz1    Baz2
Sue      Bar1    Bar2
Sue      Baz1    Baz2
```

I want to write another query that will tell me how many times each distinct `NAME` appears, and what that `NAME` is.  So something like:

```
Frank    3
Joe      2
Sue      2
```

I  found some info about a `SELECT COUNT` query [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp), but I don't have much experience working with queries yet, so I haven't been able to put all the pieces together.  It seems like it should be a pretty typical thing to do, so it can probably be done and I'm probably just missing something really simple, but I'm not sure what.  Does anyone know how this is done?  And I'm trying to do this in MS Access, so I can't use the `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` method that the site I linked mentions.

Comment: Can you use ``select name, count(*) from tablename group by name``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Select [Name], COUNT(Foo1) AS Cnt from TableName GROUP BY [Name] ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

You have to put the field name "Name" in brackets, because it's a reserved word.  In the future, try to avoid using reserved words for field names, it will make your life easier.  For example, rename the field "Name" to be "FName" or something.  Then you never have to worry about using the brackets.

Comment: Ah, I tried something so close to this, but I didn't have the `GROUP BY`.  Thanks!